# Is there any way to post an <a> within tweet or post a link with text displayed instead of url?

Tags: php, laravel, twitter

I am using https://github.com/thujohn/twitter to tweet from my CMS.

I want to add a link in that tweet. I can simply pass the url as text, which will be processed automatically, but how can I add a url but the display text will be "Read more" or "click here" or some thing like that?

Here is my current code -

```
Twitter::postTweet(['status' => 'Sample title - http://www.example.com/']);
```

`http://www.example.com/` should be displayed as **Read more** but the link will be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Twitter doesn't allow you to specify link text for the link that doesn't match the URL. (Though APIs or otherwise).

Comment: Ok. So, I have to pass the url as text only and it will convert automatically.